# C# WPF дополнительное свойство

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка с Foreground и Background, когда IsMouseOver Background изменяется на другой цвет. Вопрос: можно ли держать дополнительный цвет для Background'a когда IsMouseOver == true в отдельном свойстве? Чтобы кнопке можно было задать не только Foreground и Background но и какой-небудь HighlightBackground

Comment: Можно. Именно для этого существуют Attached Property

Comment: @АндрейNOP пробовал, не могу засетить attached property как value в тригере IsMouseOver

Comment: Разберите этот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852624/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP помогло, спасибо