# Задать значение DP для UserControl'a, который находится в стиле

Tags: c#, wpf

Создал новый UserControl, в нем сделал Dependency Property:

```
public bool CanManageWindow {
        get => (bool) GetValue(CanManageWindowProperty);
        set => SetValue(CanManageWindowProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CanManageWindow.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanManageWindowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CanManageWindow", typeof(bool), typeof(WindowsControl), new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

После этого создал глобальный стиль для окна:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            ...
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Grid>
                            <local:WindowsControl VerticalAlignment="Top"></local:WindowsControl>
                            <Border Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                <AdornerDecorator>
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </AdornerDecorator>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Как мне теперь, создавая очередное окно из его свойств дотянуться до `CanManageWindow` UserControl'a, входящего в стиль этого окна?

Т.е условно -

```
<Window
x:Name="BestMainWindow" x:Class="Blablbabla.MainWindow"
CanManageWindow="True"> ... </Window>
```

Comment: Вам придется добавить AP для окна и пробросить его примерно как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/706321/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP возможно, вы неправильно поняли мой вопрос. Я знаю, как пробросить DP, мне нужно именно иметь возможность пробросить его из аргументов окна, наследующего стиль, те `<Window CanManageWindow="True" .../>`. Если это делается через AP, то я не могу понять, как добавить их к окну.

Comment: Именно через AP, вот пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852624/218063 стиль окна параметризируется так же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать это нужно через Attached Property, [как здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852624/218063).

Конкретно для этого варианта, дополняем DP, реализовывая AP

```
public bool CanManageWindow {
    get => (bool) GetValue(CanManageWindowProperty);
    set => SetValue(CanManageWindowProperty, value);
}

public static bool GetCanManageWindow(DependencyObject obj) => (bool) obj.GetValue(CanManageWindowProperty);

public static void SetCanManageWindow(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(CanManageWindowProperty, value);

public static readonly DependencyProperty CanManageWindowProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CanManageWindow", typeof(bool), typeof(WindowsControl), new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

В стиле переписываем определение UserControl'a:

```
<local:WindowsControl x:Name="WC" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsCloseWindow="{TemplateBinding local:WindowsControl.IsCloseWindow}" CanManageWindow="{TemplateBinding local:WindowsControl.CanManageWindow}"></local:WindowsControl>
```

И теперь в любом окне мы можем написать:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SKProCHLauncher" <-- Тут название вашего пространства имен
local:WindowsControl.CanManageWindow="True"
```

И это будет работать.

P.S. В конкретном случае - нужно еще явно в окне указать стиль, или посмотреть [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987925).