# Стиль с TargetType в App.xaml игнорируется

Tags: c#, wpf

В app.xaml объявлен стиль:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            ...
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            ...
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

При этом `WindowStyle` не применяется к окнам автоматически, а только если напрямую задать в них стиль: `Style="{DynamicResource WindowStyle}"`. Почему так происходит?

P.S. В данном контексте считаю содержимое стиля бесполезным, если это не так - напишите, прикреплю.

Comment: Потому что вы указали ключ, стили с ключом автоматически не применяются, пробуйте убрать `x:Key="WindowStyle"`

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет, убирание ключа не помогло.

Comment: Да, для Window почему-то это не работает, хотя работает для любых контролов. В таком случае, остается переопределить метаданные в коде, примерно как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41961055/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP работает, оформите, как ответ.

Comment: Оформите самостоятельно, мне писать рабочий пример, проверять и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае Window это не работает, хотя работает для любых других контролов. В таком случае, остается переопределить метаданные в коде, [как тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41961055/6766879):

В app.xaml добавить

```
FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
    {
        DefaultValue = Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(Window))
    });
```